# upon execution of my log in page i receive error message 404, how do i solve this?

Tags: php, html

i have sucessfully created a sign up page however i am now trying to create a log in page using php and PDO, the form on the html side of things i have no issue with however when it comes to the php side i seem to be doing something wrong as i am greeted with error 404 upon submission of log in information...this is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

//configuration
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$db="movie1";

// Database connection
try {
    $handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db", "$dbusername", "$dbpassword");
    $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "connected";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("something failed");
}

// new data
$user = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($user == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'username required'
        $errflag = true;
}

if($password == ''){
    $errmsg_arr[] = ' password required';
    $errflag = true;
}
 // query

$result = $handle->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username= ? AND password = ?");
$result->bindParam('?', $user);
$result->bindParam('?', $password);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if ($rows > 0) {
    header("location: home.php");
}
else{
    $errmsg_arr[]= 'Username and password not found';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}

?>
```

and this is the html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>log in</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<form class="w3-container w3-card-4" action="login.php" method="post">
    <h2 class="w3-text-black">Log in</h2>
    <p>Log in</p>
    <p>
        <label class="w3-text-black"><b>username</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username"></p>
    <p>
        <label class="w3-text-black"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="password" type="text" placeholder="password"></p>

    <p>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-black">Log in</button></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

however once I enter the correct log in information and submit the form I and greeted by error 404, where am I going wrong?

Comment: do you have a login.php file ? what is the url you see in the browser

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha yes, the first set of code provided is the login.php file

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: Do you have a `home.php`?

Comment: @aynber yes, the following is the code for home.php <?php
<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:50px;font-family:arial;font-size:20px;">
    Congrats!<br>
 You've Benn Successfully Entered<br>
 In The<br>
 System<br>
</div>
    
?>

Comment: Are all 3 files in the same directory? You can also check your web server logs to find the exact url that's throwing the 404.

Comment: Do you have an `index.php`?

Comment: @waz25 you need to debug this. comment `header("location:` codes and add echo statements and see where is the issue

Comment: @aynber yes, all files are in the same directory

Comment: @FabianGillenius yeah

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha managed to get around the error and was greeted with another one after I had debugged the code

Comment: @waz25 what is the new error ?

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha  Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens on line 39 ($result->execute();)